# how to connect 3 sortable list by jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I got stuck with jquery sortable. Here I need to implement the sortable connect on 3 lists

I want functionality like this :

1. I can drag  elements from sortable1  list to sortable2 and sortable3 where all items will be remain same in sortable1(ie copy item from sortable1 to sortable2 and sortable3) and also sortable2 and sortable3 are not connected with each other.
2. after drag from sortable1 the items in sortable2 and sortable3 should be unique.

   ```
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">

       <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>

       <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
   </ul>


   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
   <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, just use connectWith property,

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith

for example:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px black; }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
  </style>
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#sortable1").sortable({
              connectWith: "#sortable2, #sortable3"
          }).disableSelection();

          $("#sortable2").sortable({
              connectWith: "#sortable1"
          }).disableSelection();

          $("#sortable3").sortable({
              connectWith: "#sortable1"
          }).disableSelection();
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>

 <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this. But my question is different .. requirement is given 1. Items should be draggable to list2 and list3 and those items should remain in list1 and also every item in list2 and list3 should be unique. Thanks in advance for help...